# Word for the action or result of expressing a telephone number as letters/words

Tags: numbers, telephone

You can use the letters on a standard telephone keypad to encode/decode a number to/from letters, eg

```
439225563 -> HEY CALL ME
```

Is there a name from either the result "HEY CALL ME" or the action of converting the number to these letters/words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When some or all of a phone number is converted to letters like this, the letters are often said to be 'mapped' to the numbers:

1-800-724-6837 -> 1-800-PAINTER

The result is said to be a 'phoneword'

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneword

Answer (score 1):

**Phoneword**

> **Phonewords** are mnemonic phrases represented as alphanumeric equivalents of a telephone number. In many countries, the digits on the telephone keypad also have letters assigned. By replacing the digits of a telephone number with the corresponding letters, it is sometimes possible to form a whole or partial word, an acronym, abbreviation, or some other alphanumeric combination.
>
> [...]
>
> Although businesses typically choose phone numbers so as to correspond to particular phonewords, it is also possible to go in the other direction, and **generate** phonewords corresponding to given numbers.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneword